# Can I downgrade from Windows 8 to Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-8, downgrade

I am about to upgrade to Windows 8 Professional however I was wondering if I would be able to downgrade to Windows 7 if there are any compatibility issues and such forth.

Comment: Make a backup first.

Answer (score 3):

If you are upgrading a existing Windows 7 install you will still have your old license, you will need to re-install windows in the process of "Downgrading" so it will not save your settings like when you upgraded.

Answer (score 2):

In the past I have been able to downgrade by creating a system restore image when still in Windows 7.

Creating one can be done as explained here: [Back up your programs, system settings, and files](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Back-up-your-programs-system-settings-and-files)

Restoring it when you want to downgrade is explained here: [Restore your computer from a system image backup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Restore-your-computer-from-a-system-image-backup)

Note that restoring a system image will remove any changes made since the creation of the image. Therefor make sure to store important data on a different partition and back it up before proceeding with the system restore. Also note that it may take a while to restore your system. However, it will automatically restore your computer as it was before the installation of Windows 8.

Comment: Note that this will destroy any files created/modified since the backup...

Comment: Thank you Bob. Because I always keep my data on a separate partition I had no problems with this. I updated my answer.