# How would I back up windows 7?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to backup Windows 7 and revert upgrade to Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/493643/how-to-backup-windows-7-and-revert-upgrade-to-windows-8)

I've finally decided to go ahead and give windows 8 a try. I would feel a lot better though if there was a way I could back up my entire OS to restore to incase I dislike windows 8. How would I backup my entire OS with as small a file as possible that would be easy to go back to from windows 8? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to backup Windows 7 and revert upgrade to Windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/493643/how-to-backup-windows-7-and-revert-upgrade-to-windows-8). Also see [Can I downgrade from Windows 8 to Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/474434/can-i-downgrade-from-windows-8-to-windows-7)

Comment: if you are so worried then do not do it, otherwise virtualize Win8 with VirtualBox (or similiar) and play with it. THere are hundreds are ways to back up your system, or run more than one OS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had success with two options:

1) [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) (open source and free)

2) [Acronis True Image](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/) (pay, very good)

Comment: I was able to get Acronis for free with my Western Digital drive. Thanks, installing windows 8 now.

Comment: Great!  It worked very well for me, built a PC for a family friend and used that to create a fresh install image.  We used it at least once, which was great.  Hope you enjoy.

Comment: It's okay because after 1 hour I've already decided windows 8 is here to stay!

Comment: Always great to hear some first hand reviews, I haven't decided to take the plunge yet, but I run linux 99.9% of the time outside my 7vbox.

Comment: I plan to dual boot ubuntu with the windows 8 boot manager for development purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try "Windows 7 File Recovery".

More detail here:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/recover-data-files-in-windows-7-with-system-restore-explorer/5354