# How do I revert back to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-8-upgrade, downgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I downgrade from Windows 8 to Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/474434/can-i-downgrade-from-windows-8-to-windows-7)

So I recently install Windows 8 and I would like to revert back to my Windows 7 install using my "Windows.old" folder that was created by the upgrade utility.

I need to be able to keep all my files and programs.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

There's [an article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971760) from Microsoft on this. It's for reverting from Windows7, but the idea is the same.
Essentially, get an install disc, boot into the command prompt repair mode, move the Windows 8 system files to a new folder, then copy the Windows.old folder to your C drive. Then, restore the boot sector and Boot.ini file. By the way, the nt number is 61 for 32bit systems and 62 for 64 bit systems. (So `D:\boot\bootsect /nt61 c:`) for example.
 I believe you can do the same thing in a Linux live iso, although I've never tried it.